# Is having binary randomized unchanging neural network weights a good idea?

Tags: neural-networks, weights

I am creating a neural network to experiment with, and I was wondering:

- If I have weights randomly initialized to be either 1 or 0 for each neuron, and then I made it so that the weights cannot be changed, would that ruin the neural network? What would happen?

Note: There is no bias in this network.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Your question isn't completely clear to me. You say "would that ruin the neural network?", but what do you mean by "ruin"? And do you mean during learning or inference? If you randomly initialise the weights and then do _not_ train the network, your network won't probably be able to do anything that you want. Either you are not understanding how neural networks work or you didn't express yourself well. Please, edit your post to clarify this.

Comment: If the weights cannot change there is no point in training the network since the whole idea of a neural net is to adjust the weights to reduce training loss. I think you need help understanding neural networks. I highly recommend tutorial sequence on YouTube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZmobeGL0Yg&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xq7LwI2y8_QtvuXZedL6tQU

Comment: Worth clarifying if you mean all the weights are locked to 0 or 1 like this, or just some of them. Also, what you hope to achieve by doing this, as it seems like an unmotivated experiment